# How to overload std::vector::operator=()

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, armadillo

I need to have assignment of type std::vector = arma::vec, i.e. to assign vector from armadillo math library to a std::vector.

```
template <typename T>
std::vector<T>& std::vector<T>::operator=(arma::vec right) {
  std::size_t s(right.size());
  this->resize(s);
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < s; i++)
    *this[i] = right(i);
  return *this;
}
```

I tried this way, but the compiler is not agree:
`error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class std::vector<_RealType>’`

Is it possible to overload the assignment operator for std::vector class?

Comment: Do you know that the assignment operator cannot be overloaded as a non-member function?

Comment: Actually, this is not an attempt to overload as a non-member function. This is an ad-hoc attempt to add the overload as a new member function. This, unfortunately, will not work.

Comment: @RSahu Yes, that is why I tried `std::vector<T>::operator=(arma::vec right)`, but this is not declared inside the std::vector class, so is it possible to overloaded it for the std::vector without messing with the standard library?

Comment: Forget it. What you should do is `std_vec.assign(arma_vec.begin(), arma_vec.end());`

Comment: Or this: [conv_to](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#conv_to). People, can't you RTFM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points to consider:

1. `operator=` can be overloaded only as a member function.
2. Defining the operator function the way you have is not possible unless the function is declared as member function of the class.
3. There are easy work arounds to assign a `arma::vec`. Use them instead of trying to define an `oprator=` overload.

Example code that demonstrates how you can assign different kinds of containers to a `std::vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main()
{
   std::vector<int> a;
   int b[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   std::set<int> c{10, 20, 30, 40, 50};

   a = {std::begin(b), std::end(b)};

   for ( int el : a )
   {
      std::cout << el << " ";
   }

   std::cout << std::endl;

   a.assign(std::begin(c), std::end(c));

   for ( int el : a )
   {
      std::cout << el << " ";
   }

   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

In your case, you can use either of the following:

```
std::vector<YourType> v;
v = {std::begin(right), std::end(right)};
v.assign(std::begin(right), std::end(right));
```

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't possible to do so. It's even undefined behavior if you extend the `std` namespace unless explicitly permitted by the standard for those symbols. That said, I don't see a compiler put in resources to track that. It however could conflict with symbols already in use.

In the implementations of the STL that I know, a lot of the functions are implemented in base classes with unspecified names.

There does consist something like a casting operator: `operator std::vector<int>() const`
This needs to be added to the type that needs to be converted. However, as that's also part of a library, I don't think you have valid options.